# HTML Video How To Toggle Track Captions With Javascript

Tags: html, html5-video, caption, closed-captions

I have a video player with a track for captions:

```
<video ... >
<track src="/file.vtt" default kind="captions" srcLang="en" label="English" />
</video>
```

It loads and works great when the page loads, but I want to give users the ability to  toggle/turn captions on and off with a custom button. I don't want to use the native video controls.

I tried:

```
btnClick(){
 //get track ref
 track.mode = "hidden"
}
```

Using javascript, but it's not doing anything.

How can I control the captions/track with javascript?

Answer (score 3):

I figured it out. Instead of updating a reference to the track element, it's working if I use a reference to the video element.

```
let track = video.textTracks && video.textTracks[0]
if (track) track.mode = "hidden"
```